# How to run a method within a CCAction?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently on the brink of throwing my computer at the wall because I cannot figure this out. I have done about 200 Google searches, and every link is clicked up to like page 6. I cannot find an answer. So here's the dirt:

I want my Enemies class to contain a shoot method. Simple enough right? Well, I have the action to move the enemies in the HelloWorldLayer method. I want to find a way to have (some type of) CCAction call that method from the Enemies.m class. Please help! And @Lukman your Object Oriented Programming answer didn't work. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's what's in HelloWorldLayer.m that is necessary to the answer:

```
action = [CCSequence actions:
          [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(moveToPoint, buffDude.position)), 75)],
          [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(buffDude.position.x,buffDude.position.y)],
          nil];

CCCallFuncO *a = [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:buffDude selector:(@selector(shoot:)) object:buffDude];

CCSequence *seq = [CCSequence actions:action,a, nil];

CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq];

[buffDude runAction:repeat];
```

And here's what is in Enemies.m:

```
@implementation BigAndStrongEnemy
```

`+(id)enemy` `{`

```
BigAndStrongEnemy *enemy = nil;
if((enemy = [[[super alloc] initWithFile:@"bigAndStrongEnemy.gif"] autorelease])) {
    enemy.hp = 200;
    enemy.pointsWorth = 1000;
}
return enemy;
```

}

```
-(void)spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender {
    CCSprite *b = (CCSprite *)sender;
    [self removeChild:b cleanup:YES];
}

-(void)shoot {
    CCSprite *b = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bullet.gif"];
    b.position = ccp(self.position.x,self.position.y);
    [self addChild:b];
    [bullets addObject:b];

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake((winSize.width - (winSize.width - self.position.x)),0);

    [b runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                  [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5 position:point],
                  [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
                  nil]];
}

-(void)shoot:(id)sender {
    BigAndStrongEnemy *e = (BigAndStrongEnemy *)sender;
    [e shoot];
}

@end
```

Comment: And @ipodfreak0313 your questions didn't work. It should be obvious enough by now that you need to show your code or at least something you have worked on so that people can see exactly which part you are having problem with. Not everyone likes to guess or try to read your mind.

Comment: @Lukman i edited the question with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as i understood CCCallFunc is what you need

Answer (score 3):

hmm... hope this works:

```
id *func = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:buffDude selector:@selector(shoot)];
```

Comment: that seemed like it would work, but it doesn't. this is driving me NUTZ!!

Comment: i've never used nslog, thus i don't know how